# Prove a set is closed iff its equal to its closure

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

**Theorem**: A set is closed if and only if its equal to its closure

Heres my proof

**Proof of Theorem**: ( $\Rightarrow$ ) $A$ is closed, by def of $\overline{A}=A \cup A'$, then $A \subset \overline{A}$,

**Claim**: $A$ is closed iff $A \supset A'$
**Proof of Claim**: ( $\Rightarrow$ ) If $A$ is closed, we just need proof $\textbf{x} \in A' \Rightarrow \textbf{x} \in A$, we take contrapositive $\textbf{x} \notin A' \Rightarrow \textbf{x} \notin A$, Let $\textbf{x} \notin A'$, because $A$ is closed, then $A^c$ is open,  $\exists\ r\ \text{s.t.}\ \mathrm{B}_r(\textbf{x}) \subset A^c$. Hence $\mathrm{B}_r(\textbf{x}) \cap  A = \varnothing$, therefore $\textbf{x}$ is not a limit point of $A$, thus $\textbf{x} \in A^c \Rightarrow \textbf{x} \notin A$. Hence, $\textbf{x} \in A' \Rightarrow \textbf{x} \in A$, so $A \supset A'$
($\Leftarrow$) Let $A \supset A'$, so that $\textbf{x}$ is not a limit point of $A$, $\textbf{x} \in A^c$,$\exists\ r\ \text{s.t.}\ \mathrm{B}_r(\textbf{x}) \cap A \setminus \{\textbf{x}\} = \varnothing$. Hence $\mathrm{B}_r(\textbf{x}) \cap  A = \varnothing$ implies
$\mathrm{B}_r(\textbf{x}) \subset A^c$, so $A^c$ is open, then $A$ is closed. $\quad \blacksquare$

Hence, by Claim proof ($\Rightarrow$), $\textbf{x} \in A' \Rightarrow \textbf{x} \in A$, we have $\overline{A} \subset A \Rightarrow A = \overline{A}$.

($\Leftarrow$) Let $A = \overline{A}$, then $A = A \cup A'$, notice that $A \supset A'$. By Claim, $A$ is closed. $\quad \blacksquare$

---

Am I right?

Comment: The contrapositive of $\bf{x} \in A' \implies \bf{x} \in A$ is not correct: it should be $$\bf{x} \not\in A \implies \bf{x} \not\in A'$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $C$ a subset of a topological space $X$.

We want to prove that $C$ is closed iff $C=\overline{C}$.

If $C$ is closed, then the smallest closed set that contains $C$ is clearly $C$.

Viceversa, if $C=\overline{C}$, then $X\setminus C=X\setminus \overline{C}$ is open in $X$ because $\overline{C}$ is a closed subset. So $C$ is closed.

If you don't want to use the fact that $\overline{C}$ is closed, I will write you a more detailed proof-

Hope that helps!